# Numbers in noun phrases

Tags: numbers

What is the form and function of the cardinal number “three” in the NP “day three”? I know cardinal numbers are determiners or fused heads. I looked at Pullum and Huddleston and couldn’t find an answer.

Comment: Hi welcome to ELL! Are you also the OP of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/261813/day-three-part-of-speech-of-three)? If you simply want to ask a follow up question, you should use your other account that posted the original question and make clarifications, or you could use that account to comment on the answers below your question.

Comment: "Three" is a determinative functioning as post-head modifier of "day".

Comment: Thanks very much! I wanted the posthead determiner confirmed. Thank you.